# how to implement a details view in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to figure out how to  implement a url in a format for example locations/details/1001. Instead i keep getting a format like this locations/details?id=1001, which my routing does not like.

Here is the code i am using for this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/location/details'], { queryParams: { id: locationId } });
```

and in my routing module:

```
{ path: "locations/details/:id", component: LocationDetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.router.navigate(['/location/details/', id])

Comment: how can i get the id value later? const locationId: string | null = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id'); - is returning undefined

Comment: Try activated route.

Comment: this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']